# Identify trending topics in Twitter

Tags: twitter, machine-learning, apache-spark, k-means, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming to stream real time tweets (filter, only english tweets) and store them in Cassandra, then I am planning to run K-means/ LSI algo (using spark MLib) to identify trending topics.

I need hints on how to represent these tweets in a matrix (vector) representation. Further, I want to know if is it right to train the model with stored data and then run the model with the streamed data?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the features you are using and the language you are using.

You could represent it as a vector with all the words as columns and each value between 1 and 0 using some kind of metric like TFIDF. Then perform the k-means on a regular RDD (or sparse)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-clustering.html

https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/sparse_data_support_in_mllib1.pdf

Comment: I thought about using TF-IDF normalization, but should i store the streams first into Cassandra and then perform TF-IDF? both links are not working!

Comment: Well, the TF you could calculate on the fly, as you are getting info from tweeter as this is a local per twitter statistic. The IDF uses the overall number of documents and the documents with each term. So... you could in theory update this values on the fly as well (global variable). Probably you will need to make closed periods (daily, hourly) so that you could properly k-means the info.